# checkbox value in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

How can I check in codeigniter if a checkbox is checked or not? I need to do this to set a custom message for an error. 
I try this:

```
public function misure_validation() {
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('accetta_misure','accetta','required|md5|trim|callback_convalida_tos');
  // la funzione run ritorna un true solo se le regole sopra sono verificate
  if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
    $this->misure_db();
  } else {
    $this->nuovocosplay(); //ritorna alla schermata delle misure
  }
}

public function convalida_tos()
{
  $check = $this->input->post('accetta_misure')?1:0;
  if ($check==1) {
     return true;
  } else {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('convalida_tos', 'devi accettare i termini e le condizioni della commissione.');
    return false;
  }
}
```

of course I've set the checkbox in the view in this way

```
<?php echo form_checkbox('accetta_misure','1', FALSE); ?>
```

thank you

Comment: And what r u getting?

Comment: nothing! just the standard error set in the defaul form_validation lang file, but not my custom message

Comment: Chk my answer I hope it will work

Comment: Still looking for solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom validation message as:

```
public function misure_validation() {   

   $this->load->library('form_validation');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('accetta_misure','accetta','required|md5|trim|callback_convalida_tos'); // la funzione run ritorna un true solo se le regole sopra sono verificate 

   $this->form_validation->set_message('convalida_tos', 'devi accettare i termini e le condizioni della commissione.'); 

   if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) { 
      $this->misure_db(); 
   } 
   else { 
      $this->nuovocosplay(); //ritorna alla schermata delle misure 
   } 

}
```

**Call back function:**

```
public function convalida_tos() { 

    $check = $this->input->post('accetta_misure')?1:0; 
    if ($check==1) { 
        return true; 
    } else { 
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: nope =( always show the default message from the language file :(